# Javascript in php not working?

Tags: javascript, php

When i run this php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Nova SFI poruka '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Javascripts work fine, alert pops up, and it transfers me to wanted page...
But when i use this php instead:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){


$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_rank = $_POST['rank'];

$mail_to = 'email';
$subject = 'Rank confirmation '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n".$field_lastname."\n".$field_rank."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


try {

    // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
    // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
    if (
        !isset($_FILES['file']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['file']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters.');
    }

    // Check $_FILES['file']['error'] value.
    switch ($_FILES['file']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1000000) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    }

    // DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['file']['mime'] VALUE !!
    // Check MIME Type by yourself.
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
    }

    // You should name it uniquely.
    // DO NOT USE $_FILES['file']['name'] WITHOUT ANY VALIDATION !!
    // On this example, obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }
 ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Confirmed! We will check it in maximum 24 hours!\\nPotvrdjeno! Provericemo za maksimum 24 casa!');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
    <?php

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}

}else{ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Security answer incorect! Please try again!\\nBezbednosni odgovor netacan! Pokusajte ponovo!');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
    <?php
}
}



?>
```

It just doesn't work, I have no idea what am I doing wrong.
sorry about messy code

when it works:
http://prntscr.com/4hudk9
when it doesn't:
http://prntscr.com/4hud98

Comment: In general "does not work" immediately gets downvotes by me - it's the worst error description. You may want to debug your code first and try to find out what of the code doesn't work.

Comment: This is btw horrible code and horrible architecture! Take the time and use a boilerplate, a framework etc. and clearly split your JS, your PHP and your frontend markup. You'll thank yourself later :)

Comment: "Javascript in php" name for post was already used.
I never learned JS, or PHP, it's just logic, if it works, I'm proud, I only know HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `header()` in code block 2 is calling for plain text. You should set this to a Javascript or HTML type output. Use one of the following header() calls instead.

If you have javascript AND html in the output: 
     `header('Content-Type: text/html');`

If your output is javascript ONLY (no html tags):
     `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, now I know even more, thanks again.